# generating complete consistent theories

Tags: logic, model-theory, modal-logic

This is a model theoretic question. I was reading Kremer & Mints's [Dynamic topological logic](http://individual.utoronto.ca/philipkremer/onlinepapers/DTL.pdf) paper, and it mentioned that by a “standard argument”, every consistent formula is a member of some complete consistent theory. (The definitions for *complete*, *consistent*, and *theory* are pretty much the standard ones as defined in any undergrad logic course; they are also defined on the 8th page (page 140).)

If we have a consistent formula, it's already in S4C (which is basically S4 along with some additional axioms; these are given on the same page). Since S4C is closed under *modus ponens* and by the definition of a *theory*.

So basically, it comes down to showing that there actually exist complete consistent theories. My question is how one goes about generating such a theory. This is, I think, what they mean when they say “standard argument.” I'm probably not using creative enough search terms, but a quick Google search doesn't turn up anything too useful. Does anyone know where this “standard argument” can be found (or understand it themselves)?

Comment: I haven't checked the details of the framework you are working on, but I would imagine the idea is this: This follows from Zorn's lemma. Say that a theory $T$ decides a sentence $\phi$ iff either $T\vdash \phi$ or $T\vdash \lnot\phi$. The point is that if $T$ is consistent, and $\phi$ is a formula that $T$ does not decide, then both $T\cup\{\phi\}$ and $T\cup\{\lnot\phi\}$ are consistent. Also, if $T$ is inconsistent, then a finite subset of $T$ is inconsistent.

Comment: It follows from this that any chain of consistent extensions of a theory $T$ has a consistent theory as its union, and that a maximal chain has as its union a complete theory.

Comment: Perhaps your logic does not permit the standard argument to go through. By standard argument I mean well-order the sentences, then one by one add them to the theory unless adding results in inconsistency.

Comment: Thanks for the answers @AndréNicolas and AndresCaidedo. It turns out to be exactly that. Starting out with a consistent S we consider at each step say $\alpha$ and $\neg\alpha$, and add alpha. (if this results in an inconsistency, we add $\neg\alpha$). Thanks for the help everyone!